# How to read a tarfile object directly with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, tar, opencv3.0, mat

I have a tarball containing tiff files. I am trying to read them without extracting and saving them. Here is what I have:

```
tar = tarfile.open("filename.tar", 'r|')
for tiff in tar:
    if tiff.isfile():
        c = tar.extractfile(tiff)
```

`typ(c) = tarfile.ExFileObject`

I want to read it directly with OpenCV to get a **Mat** format. 
I can read it with PIL or matplotlib to get a numpy array and they both work like a charm, but I didn't find any recent or convenient way to convert a numpy array to Mat format.
Again, I want to know if there is a way that I can read it directly without saving it and reading it.

In case there is no way to read it directly and I have to convert a numpy array to Mat, I've tried everything I could find and all the solutions are for previous versions and non of them worked for me. 
I found these:

[pyopencv](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyopencv/): has this: `pyopencv.Mat.from_pil_image(image)`

or [ctypes-opencv](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ctypes-opencv/)

which work with python 2 and older versions of opencv

I also found:

[pyboostcvconverter](https://github.com/Algomorph/pyboostcvconverter)

[NUMPY <=> OpenCV's cv::Mat converter](https://github.com/spillai/numpy-opencv-converter)

but all of them are old and non of them work for me.

I appreciate if anyone can help.

I am using python 3.6
opencv 3.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you get a *"bytes object*" if you do a `read()` on the result of `tar.extract file()`. Then you can convert that to a Numpy `ndarray` and use **OpenCV** `imdecode()` to unpack the TIF format from the memory buffer into an image.

This code works for me - though I seem to alternate between reading 266 byte useless files and TIF images from my tarfile - I don't know why that is but if you don't get them, you can just remove the `if` statement that checks for useless 266 byte files!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import sys
import tarfile                                                                              
import numpy as np

tar = tarfile.open('images.tar','r|') 
for f in tar:
   # Extract an image
   c = tar.extractfile(f).read()
   if sys.getsizeof(c) > 266:
      print(sys.getsizeof(c))
      na = np.frombuffer(c, dtype=np.uint8)
      im = cv2.imdecode(na, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
      cv2.imshow('Extracted', im)
```

If anyone knows what the 266 byte useless thing is, please tell me and we'll all learn something! Thank you.

**Keywords**: Python, OpenCV, Numpy, np.array, tar, tar file, archive, extract, in-memory, imdecode, TIF, TIFF, bytes object

Comment: It works! To answer your question I think that 256 byte object is a folder. that's why I have ```if tiff.isfile()``` in mine.